# MyFaces Context Loading troubles

Tags: jsf, myfaces, trinidad

> I met in several times a problem to load myfaces context, i've solved it by recreating maven project like these : mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse, whithout knowing the real cause, now i am blocked because the problem has reappeared, here is the details  :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application

> 11:17:54,181 INFO  [MyfacesConfig] Starting up Tomahawk on the MyFaces-JSF-Implementation
>   11:17:54,415 INFO  [FacesConfigurator] Reading standard config META-INF/standard-faces->config.xml
>   11:17:54,496 ERROR [Digester] Digester.getParser: 
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This parser does not support specification "null" >version "null"
>     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.setXIncludeAware(SAXParserFactory.java:448)
>     at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getFactory(Digester.java:534)
>     at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getParser(Digester.java:786)
>     at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:1058)
>     at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1863)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.getFacesConfig(>DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.java:215)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.getFacesConfig(>DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.java:54)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.feedStandardConfig(FacesConfigurator.java:442)
>     at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:404)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitiali>zer.java:144)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitiali>zer.java:72)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:>96)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletCo>ntextListener.java:89)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
>   11:17:54,526 ERROR [AbstractFacesInitializer] An error occured while initializing MyFaces: >null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:1058)
>     at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1863)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.getFacesConfig(>DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.java:215)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.config.impl.digester.DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.getFacesConfig(>DigesterFacesConfigUnmarshallerImpl.java:54)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.feedStandardConfig(FacesConfigurator.java:442)
>     at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:404)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitiali>zer.java:144)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitiali>zer.java:72)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:>96)
>     at >org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletCo>ntextListener.java:89)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
>   11:17:54,527 INFO  [StartupServletContextListener] Checking for >plugins:org.apache.myfaces.FACES_INIT_PLUGINS
>   29 mars 2012 11:17:55 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens >if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all >configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary >libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container >for any exceptions!
>   If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some >special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and >a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
>   A typical config looks like this;
>   
>    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
>
> at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:106)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:137)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1228)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1147)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1043)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5284)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5279)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
>   29 mars 2012 11:17:55 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
>   GRAVE: La servlet /commercialWeb a généré une exception "load()"
>
> My Pom.xml file is :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>8.4-701.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>


    <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId> 
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version> <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>commons-logging</groupId> 
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-webflow.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate and JPA dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge</groupId>
        <artifactId>jeval</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad</groupId>
        <artifactId>trinidad-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad</groupId>
        <artifactId>trinidad-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jetty is needed if you're are not using the CXFServlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>dz.gov.mtp.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>commun</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: When I've removes all the Geotools Dependencies gt-..., the myfaces context has started, but i still ignoring witch dependencies that created the conflict :(

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error you did, when I saw [this post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?53208-MyFaces1-2-2-SpringWebFlow-2-RC1-Spring-Centric-MVC), which solved it.

Basically, my build was accidentally adding *javax.servlet-5.1.12.jar* and *jsp-api-2.1.jar*, that were coming into conflict against Tomcat's implementations of these same APIs.

Maybe one of those gt-*.jar files would happen to be a copy of the servlet/jsp libraries?

Comment: the jsp-api invoke the problem of myfaces factory beacause it creates a conflict with the tomcat libs